# Tricky query: getting Count of one column with 2 conditions for another distinct column

Tags: php, mysql

I am struggling with a challenging query.

I have 2 tables: `posts`, `answers`

`posts` has `ID`, `PID`, `name`
`answers` has `ID`, `PID`, `approved`

`ID` is the user ID, `PID` is the post ID.

What I am trying to do is list all the post names (`posts.name`) and how many unique people (`ID`s) have replied to their posts. The trick is that I only want to count replies that are approved (`answers.approved = 'Y'`) AND I do not want to count the person who created the post, so (`post.ID != answers.ID`).

So the results should show something like:

```
Name       People with Approved Replies
Name 1                               10
Name 2                                7
```

My current code is a mess and the wrong approach. It only gives one result and the count of replies is way off/far too high. But here is what I have currently:

```
$results = $dbh->prepare("select COUNT(DISTINCT answers.ID) AS reply,
 posts.ID,    
 posts.PID,
 posts.name,
 answers.PID,
 answers.approved
FROM answers
LEFT JOIN posts ON answers.PID=posts.PID
WHERE (answers.approved = 'Y') LIMIT 10
GROUP BY answer.ID");

$results->execute();
$row = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: you don't have a group-by clause, so you're getting a "global" count, not a per-post count.

Comment: Also, note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless.

Comment: Thanks. what would I group-by in this query?

Comment: I added the GROUP BY but still get same exact number for writing, which is still far too large a number.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Desired result set is show in original post. Name and "People with approved replies"

Answer (score 1):

I think this query should do what you want

```
SELECT 
    p.name,
    p.id,
    p.pid,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) 
     FROM answers 
     WHERE  answers.pid = p.pid 
     AND    answers.approved = 'Y' 
     AND    answers.id != p.id) as reply
FROM posts p
```

This will select posts name , id , user id and count of distinct approved answers

Comment: Looks close, but not getting any results. Something seems off in the line (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id)...

Comment: I have updated my query , you dont really need to join answers , count distinct id - is totally fine , if id - is the user id in answers ( and thats what you want to count )

Comment: But wouldn't I need to join the two tables so I can get the post name for the total approved answers?

Comment: you are already selecting from the posts table , and you can directly get posts.name

Comment: Got ya. Well, still no results. I'll keep tinkering with this approach. I added w.PID and w.approved to your select, but still nothing. If you see anything else please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: wait , you want people whose replies got approved or you want a post and how many approved replies does this post have ? I am confused

Comment: The latter….I want the display the post name and how many approved replies this post has.